# I would like to make the below code to execute synchronous

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Below is the code I want to make synchronous

```
subtractBtn.addEventListener("click",  (e) => {

    console.log("executing");
    readDatafromDB();
    console.log("executing after read");

});



function readDatafromDB() {

    const db_store = createTransaction("readwrite");
    const data = db_store.get(79);

    console.log("executing 2");
    
    data.onsuccess =  function(e) {       
        var data = e.target.result;
        console.log("data is: ", data);
    };

    data.onerror = function(e) {

    };
    console.log("executing 4");
}
```

Since reading data from indexedDB is async the following the being printed:

```
executing
executing 2
executing 4
executing after read
data is:
```

However, I would want the code to execute in the below way synchronously

```
executing
executing 2
data is: 
executing 4
executing after read
```

I tried in all possible, and seems impossible

Comment: Create a promise, return it from the function, await for it, and resolve it in the callbacks?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen , i tired it, but unable to achieve it. could you please share a sample code, so that I can check and try

Comment: You can't make it synchronous. You can use a promise to write sequential code instead of passing callbacks around. See the linked question for how to convert to promises.

Comment: Do you know https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code with promise:

```
subtractBtn.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
    console.log("executing");
    await readDatafromDB();
    console.log("executing after read");
});

function readDatafromDB() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const db_store = createTransaction("readwrite");
        const data = db_store.get(79);

        console.log("executing 2");

        data.onsuccess = function (e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
            console.log("data is: ", data);
            console.log("executing 4");
            resolve(); // Resolve the promise once the data is retrieved
        };

        data.onerror = function (e) {
            reject(e); // Reject the promise if an error occurs
        };
    });
}
```

I hope this helps